# Laravel 6: how do I send user_id with role_id(s) to controller, in order to sync user_role pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization, many-to-many

I'm pretty new to Laravel and need help. I'm creating an admin page where users can be assigned multiple roles by means of checkboxes. I have the usual many-to-many relationships set up and a pivot table, "roles_users" with two columns: role_id and user_id. Users' various roles display fine, but I'm having trouble with the update function. My form sends an array of roles to admincontroller@update, but of course they need to be associated with users -- and I can't figure out how to do that.

Here's my form:

```
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.update') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                @foreach ($roles as $role)
                <th>{{ $role->name }}</th>
                @endforeach
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="user[]" value="{{ $user->id }}">
                    @foreach($roles as $role)
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="roles[]" value={{ $role->id }}
                            @if (in_array($role->id, $user->roles->pluck('id')->toArray() ))
                                checked ="1"
                            @endif />
                        </td>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="tableSubmit" value="Update" />
```

Here's my update method:

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        $id = $request->input('user');
        $user = User::with('roles')->find($id);
        $user->roles()->sync(($request->roles), false);

        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

This all throws an error, "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::roles does not exist." But of course I do have a roles() method in my User model:

```
    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

How do I pass through the user_id with the roles' ids, so that the sync method works? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You want to send all users and roles at the same time? Or only update one user at time?

Comment: All users and roles at the same time. I believe "sync" is supposed to handle that -- but I could be wrong!

Comment: Ok but in this case, what `->find($id);` should retrieve?

Comment: Uhh ... good point. That doesn't make sense, does it. But I don't know how to set it up correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my revised update method. It seems to work. I wonder if there's a more elegant solution, one that doesn't need a "foreach"?

```
    public function update(Request $request) {

        $users = (array_keys($request->roles)); // gets the user ids

        foreach($users as $u) {
            $user = User::find($u);
            $user->roles()->sync(array_values($request->roles[$u]));
        }

        return redirect('/admin');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are using the with method directly to the collection, the correct way is:

```
$user = User::where('id',$id)->with('roles')->first();
```

Hope it works!

**EDIT:**

Not sure why is a "false" after the array inside the sync method, try changing to this:

```
$user->roles()->sync($request->roles);
```

Comment: Seems like a step in the right direction, but doesn't quite work. It gets rid of the error, but new data isn't being added to the user_role table. (I guess I'm also confused about the "first()" method. Does it mean only the first user's roles will be updated?)

Comment: Try with the edit I made, the first() method return the first user of the "query", its similar to find ;)

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with exactly your edit. Pivot table remains unaffected.

Comment: Can you retrieve how $request->roles looks? maybe something is wrong with it?

Comment: It's just an array of all the checked boxes: array:9 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
  3 => "1"
  4 => "1"
  5 => "2"
  6 => "1"
  7 => "2"
  8 => "1"
]

Comment: So it doesn't connect roles to users. I need to send an array to the update method that will identify which roles go with which user. I thought about using an "each" method, but I'm not sure that will actually work. Perhaps I need a multidimensional array, but I'm not sure how to build that in the blade code, and I wonder if there's a simpler way. (By the way, I really appreciate your help with this!)

Comment: what are the values of the values? (1,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,1) are they the ids of the roles? or is the value selected in the checkboxes? as in the laravel docs, the array must be an array of ids, and its weird that the ids can be repeated, if we clarify this, you may have this fixed! cheers

Comment: Yes, they're the ids of the roles -- and yes, they are the ones that were selected in the checkboxes. (So they're not the old roles only, obtained from "$user->roles->pluck('id')", but also the new ones being passed to the update method.

Comment: I've tried this for the update method: ```         $users = collect($request->input('user'));
        // $users = Array(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, ...)
        foreach($users as $user) {
            $u = User::find($user);
            $u->roles()->sync($request->roles);
        } ``` But the result is that each user has as many roles as that of the single user with the most roles! In other words, it doesn't attach roles to particular users; it just throws all the roles together and attaches them to all users! I can't figure out how to limit the roles to particular users.

Comment: why are you doing a loop for each user? you only want to update the roles of single user no?

Comment: No, I want to update many users with one click. I have a table of users with a row of checkboxes for each, so that the admin can edit several at once and then click once to update many. Right now, the selected roles are all getting passed as one array, so they get assigned to all users indiscriminately. I'm trying to pass the roles selected for each user to the update method, so that all users+roles can be updated with one click.

Comment: you have also an array of users?? if yes.. you would need a multidimensional array of roles , am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. A multidimensional array of users and their roles. I don't have much experience with that sort of thing. Any advice about how to build it?

Comment: Okay, so I'm getting there. I changed my form so that the checkboxes now have "name=roles[ {{$user->id}} ][]" This sends a two-dimensional array with the data I need:   "2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
  ]"  ... where the key of the parent array is the user_id and the value of the child array is the role_id. So far so good. Now I want to use the sync method to update the pivot table. The example in the docs looks like this: "$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);"

Comment: But my 2D array doesn't have named indexes, so how would I use my data in a sync method of this kind?

Comment: "$user->roles()->sync($request->roles['user_id']['role_id']);" returns an error: "undefined index: 'user_id'".

Comment: Sorry @user9194865 didn't see these messages... the best way to loop on a multidimensional array is to use 2 nested for loops and then in your last codes change the user_id and role_id by the int used in the loop, for example: `$user->roles()->sync($request->roles[i][j]);` if you used i to loop the user's ids and a j to loop the roles ids and sorry again!